# How to pass the data with dynamic key in semantic UI vue dropdown?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dropdown, semantic-ui

I am facing an issue with `semantic-ui-vue` dropdown.

Here is my sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/3qknm52pm5.

In my sandbox, I have two dropdowns: `From` and `To`.

`From` shows the correct values and `To` doesn't due to key mismatch.

My `App.vue` contain this script

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      from: [],
      to: [],
      fromCollection: [
        {
          value: "abc@gmail.com",
          text: "abc@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          value: "def@gmail.com",
          text: "def@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          value: "qwerty@gmail.com",
          text: "qwerty@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          value: "shubham@gmail.com",
          text: "shubham@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      toCollection: [
        {
          email: "abc@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          email: "def@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          email: "qwerty@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          email: "shubham@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

and the component I used for both of them are

```
<sui-dropdown
      fluid
      multiple
      :options="fromCollection"
      placeholder="from"
      selection
      v-model="from"
      search
      :allowAdditions="true"
      text="email"
    />
<sui-dropdown
      fluid
      multiple
      :options="toCollection"
      placeholder="from"
      selection
      v-model="to"
      search
      :allowAdditions="true"
      text="email"
    />
```

The 1st dropdown shows the correct values because I have passed the data from `fromCollection` whereas the 2nd dropdown doesn't show any text because I have passed the data from `toCollection` which has different key names.

Can someone help me to pass the data with dynamic keys like `toCollection`?

I couldn't find anything related in the [documentation](https://semantic-ui-vue.github.io/#/modules/dropdown).
Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to define field name for dropdown

only use computed to regenerate new array for it

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/2404q1ox3n)

Comment: Brilliant solution!